# Enterprise Architect's XSD generator generates ref attribute instead of name attribute

Tags: xsd, uml, enterprise-architect

Using the XML Schema toolbox, I have created the following diagram:

[image: UML-diagram-created]

After generating the XSD, I get the following result:

[image: XSD-generated]

Please note that the association is represented by

```
<xs:element ref="lib:Author"   >
```

Instead, I would like to have:

```
<xs:element name="author" type="lib:Author"   >
```

How should I change the model to achieve this in Enterprise Architect?

Answer (score 6):

The solution is to add a tagged value 'anonymousRole=false' to the association, as follows:

[image: taggedvalue-anonymousRole]

Alternatively, this setting can be made at a global level, as a package property:

[image: package-property-anonymousRole]